# How do I get the average for each make while only considering a dealer's most current inventory?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
  pk          serial PRIMARY KEY
, make        text
, inventory   numeric
, dealer      text
, updated     date
);
```

And the following data:

```
INSERT INTO inventory (make, inventory, dealer, updated) 
VALUES 
('Toyota', 11, 'Jason', '2013-12-31'),
('Toyota', 47, 'Erika', '2013-12-31'),
('Toyota', 18, 'Jason', '2014-12-31'),
('Toyota', 7, 'Jason', '2015-03-31'),
('Toyota', 83, 'James', '2013-12-31'),
('Toyota', 45, 'Erika', '2014-02-28'),
('Honda', 17, 'James', '2013-12-31'),
('Ford', 32, 'Alan', '2015-07-31'),
('BMW', 98, 'Tom', '2013-05-05'),
('Honda', 43, 'Mary', '2014-06-14'),
('Honda', 9, 'Ronald', '2015-06-04'),
('Mercedes', 11, 'Jason', '2014-01-31'),
('Buick', 23, 'Jason', '2014-08-31'),
('Honda', 15, 'Mary', '2015-08-31')
```

Each dealer uploads their inventory for each make periodically. I'd like to get the average inventory for each make of car but only use the most recent inventory number for each dealer.

I can do it one-by-one for each make:

```
SELECT make, AVG(inventory) FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT ON (dealer) dealer, * FROM inventory WHERE make = 'Toyota' ORDER BY dealer, updated DESC) t
GROUP BY make
```

The downside is I have to run this query one at a time and have to know ahead of time what makes to run....I'd like to just do 1 query and be done with it so that the final outcome is:

```
make     |   avg
---------|----------
Toyota   |  45.00000
Honda    |  13.66667
Ford     |  32.00000
BMW      |  98.00000
Mercedes |  11.00000
Buick    |  23.00000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just include `make` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT make, AVG(inventory)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (make, dealer) i.*
      FROM inventory i
      ORDER BY make, dealer, updated DESC
     ) t
GROUP BY make;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is by using `ROW_NUMBER` window function to identify the latest `inventory` per `make` and `dealer` combination

```
SELECT make, 
       Avg(inventory) 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY make, dealer ORDER BY updated DESC)rn, 
               make, 
               inventory, 
               dealer, 
               updated 
        FROM   inventory) A 
WHERE  rn = 1 
GROUP  BY make
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/67218/1)

Comment: Will this be faster than Gordon Linoff's answer? I've never used Row_number nor partitition before (I am a recent convert to postgresql).

Comment: @kristen - Better check with your real data. Even am not a `postgre` guy.